# How to set color to string inside bracket in textarea input in angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs, textarea

**Expected Result**

I want to change the **CSS/color** of the string **inside the bracket** in **textarea** input in angularjs

**Eaxmple:**
[image]

**MyCode:**

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <span ng-click="appResponse(response,displayName)">{{displayName}}</span>
    <textarea ng-model="response.value" class="responseData" cols="80"></textarea>
</div>
```

**AngularJs Controller Code :**

```
  <script>
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.displayName = "testString";
        $scope.appResponse = function(responseValue, tagsValue) {
            responseValue.value += ' ' + '(' + tagsValue + ')';
            focus('responseData');
        };
    });
</script>
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/34075/

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: http://yavorskiy.github.io/angular-input-highlight/

Comment: Hi anu i update in fiddle